# What may have caused an Interactive Services Detection error?

Tags: windows-7, runtime-error

[image]
I did look at the message. The secured desktop showed me nothing.

I am wondering as to what may have caused this problem ?

I was running `BlueStacks` at the time. I am assuming that may have caused an issue because after I viewed the message, it stopped working and when I terminated it, the dialog box disappeared.

Any clues will be appreciated as to what may have caused it.
*Note: [THIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2011/03/14/troubleshooting-interactive-services-detection.aspx) was of little help*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

starting since Vista services are no longer running in the same session like the first user ([Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx)). When a service tries to display a messagebox you get this warning.

Get an update for `BlueStacks` and hope that this fixes it.

Comment: Yes, I did get that. However, when I clicked on the `View Message` , it did not show anything. I am assuming it was BlueStacks' responsibility to generate a message box ?

Comment: If you run the tool at this time, it was causing it. I have no idea why you can't see this in the dialog.